# How to move a pixel in glsl?

Tags: glsl, translation, pixel

Okay, let's say I have a ping pong shader setup. One pixel in the image has color other than 0. The red and blue components of the color define where the pixel should move. (v*r*2-0.5 = dx ... v is a constant)

Now how would I go about moving this pixel by the given amount encoded in the color value? I can't paint to another fragment then the one that's being processed, I can't seem to transfer the information "forward". Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Beware, my answer contains a link that might be pretty hard on your GPU.  It's a working breakout-style game in a single shader.

http://glsl.heroku.com/e#456.15

You asked about transfering information "forward", and in this example it is done by providing a texturemap of the previous animation frame to the shader.  The current frame needs to know where the ball and bricks were in the previous frame.

The moving ball does encode its current direction in a color, like this:

```
vec3 Ball(bool x, bool y)
{
    // Draw ball with indicated direction
    return vec3(1.0, x ? 0.9 : 1.0, y ? 0.9 : 1.0);
}
```

However, we can't expect the user to see a single-pixel ball.  Thus a "fake ball" is created as a larger white dot in the wake of the real single-pixel ball.

Texture sampling is used to examine a 5x5 area in the previous animation frame around the current pixel, to see if the current pixel is now in the "wake" of the real ball's direction of travel.

```
// Draw fake ball and bonus pixels around actuals from last frame
for (float x = -2.0; x <= 2.0; x += 1.0)
{
    for (float y = -2.0; y <= 2.0; y += 1.0)
    {
        if (IsBonus(texture2D(backbuffer, position + vec2(x, y) * pixel).rgb))
        {
            me.rgb = fakebonus;
        }
        if ((abs(x) < 2.0) || (abs(y) < 2.0))
        {
            if (IsAnyBall(texture2D(backbuffer,
                position + vec2(x, y) * pixel).rgb))
            {
                me.rgb = fakeball;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additional code in this example checks to see if the ball has come in contact with a paddle or brick, and takes appropriate steps.

In your original question you also mention that you would like color to control velocity of the ball, unfortunately this is much harder.  Controlling velocity implies you would have to sample a much larger number of surrounding pixels to see if any of them have the correct velocity to land on the pixel being rendered.  I suspect you'll need help from the host app to handle velocity.